# join icons in a font with CSS

Tags: css, fonts, icons

**EDIT :** For confidentiality reasons I am forced to delete this topic.

I have found the answer : 
in the comment below, delete the `position: absolute`in the `:after` element. This does the trick.

Thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not give `position: absolute` for **all** the icons. Instead specify it specifically to that element.

```
<div class="joined-icons">
  <i class="icon-test xs"></i>
</div>
```

And in you SCSS:

```
.joined-icons {
  .icon-test {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    &:before {
      content: '\F018';
      position: absolute;
    }
    &:after {
      content: '\F019';
      position: absolute;
    }
  }
}
```

The above code only affect all the icons inside `div.joined-icons`. So you will be alright.